# Call page PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some difficulties to call PHP script with:

```
$("#tata").click(function(){


    $.ajax({

        url : 'http://localhost/joomla/modules/mod_visitor/helper.php' ,
        type : 'GET' ,

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },

        error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
        console.log("no")
    }

});

});
```

But my alert is empty... I am sure that the URL is correct, because if I add in my PHP file HTML code it appear on my alert!

I am sure that my PHP code works

PHP file:

```
 echo "lalalala";
$getData = new mod_visitor();
$writeData = new  writeData();
$urlPart1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$urlPart2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pageEnCours = $urlPart1 .= $urlPart2;
$getData->get_ip();
$getData->LookupIP($GLOBALS['domain']);


$getData->ValidateIP($GLOBALS['domain']);




if ($GLOBALS['domain'] && $pageEnCours != preg_match("#localhost/joomla/$#", $pageEnCours)) {
    $GLOBALS['domain'] = trim($GLOBALS['domain']);

    if ($getData->ValidateIP($GLOBALS['domain'])) {
        echo "cc";
        $result = $getData->LookupIP($GLOBALS['domain']);
        $writeData->write_domain($result);
    } else {
        echo "erreur";
        $writeData->write_error();
    };

} else {
    echo "je ne rentre pas dans la boucle";
};

echo $pageEnCours;
echo $GLOBALS['domain'];
```

Comment: do you have an php tag in your phpfile ? something like <?

Comment: yes i have php tag

Comment: have you checked your error logs ? maybe some missing includes ?

Answer (score 3):

Parse the dataType to 'json'
Add `dataType: 'json'` to the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/joomla/modules/mod_visitor/helper.php' ,
    type : 'GET' ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
    console.log("no")
}
```

And echo back as JSON in your php

```
<?php
    echo json_encode('lalala');
?>
```

If you want to return multiple items, you can return them as an array

```
<?php
    $return = array(
        'pageEnCours' => $urlPart1 . $urlPart2,
        'domain' => $GLOBALS['domain']
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

And get the items client-side

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data.pageEnCours, data.domain);
}
```

Comment: But the code under the echo is not interpreted... why ?

Comment: Because `echo` ends the AJAX call and echo's things back to the client-side

Comment: but my aim is to execute the code, the echo are here just for testing, when I take it off, my script is not executing (normally my script insert data into a log file)

Comment: For testing you can use the browser's console (network tab) to see the response. Create a variable that is false by default or true if all goes well. `echo` that variable to your client-side code and you can see if it's true or false.

Comment: hmm, its the first time,  i have heard that there is only one echo possible in an php script (wondering why my scripts and ajaxcalls execute with several echos since years  ). may be it is some very special behavior of joomla , i dont know. also i dont know, why to change dataType to json as in the question is no json at all. as the purpose of an ajax call is to generate an output and execute some code with will be present in the variable data in the success branch. if there is no dataType specified the response will be guessed. so the response should result in a long string